# DRUPAL 7: insert images via URL instead of via "file-upload"

Tags: media

My boss asked me to edit an existing page (in which is already possible insert text and images) in order to be able to **insert images not only by uploading them from local pc but also via Remote URL**.

My version is **7.31** and is already installed "[File Field Sources](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_sources)" module that SHOULD be the most useful to achieve desired behaviour.

My questions are:

1. After entered in Edit Mode of a specific page, how to verify
   which module is actually used to manage images uploads?
2. In case that it is already "[File Field Sources](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_sources)", how to configure it to
   be able to put remote URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are having problem to use the module File Field Sources.

Use below steps

1. Download and install the module
2. Edit any image field, for ex. Article content type is having image field. Let's use this module over there.
3. Go to URL : `admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields`
4. Edit the field `field_image`
5. Check the option to use remote URL there. See screenshot. [image]
6. Create article content and see there option to use remote URL in image field. See attachment. [image]